# GORM query criteria for nested hasOne entity

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to create GORM criteria query filtering by a property of sub-entity. So there are such entities:

```
class PaymentEntry {

  static hasOne = [category: PaymentCategory]

  static constraints = {
    category(nullable: true)
  }

  // other stuff
}

class PaymentCategory {

  static hasMany = [payments: PaymentEntry]

  // other stuff  
}
```

Now I'm trying to select PaymentEntries, with specific categories. I was trying something like this:

```
def c = PaymentEntry.createCriteria()

def res = c {
  'in'("category", categories)
}
```

`categories` here is a list of `PaymentCategory` entities, selected earlier.

Unfortunately, this fails. Grails throws NoSuchMethodException.

Comment: Which Grails version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have inList.
Try this:

```
def res = c {
  inList("category", categories)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems. `hasOne` is meant for one-to-one [associations](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/grails-domain-class-associations/), yet you actually have a one-to-many. So the first step is to fix the associations, possibly like this:

```
class PaymentEntry {

  static belongsTo = [category: PaymentCategory]

  static constraints = {
    category(nullable: true)
  }

  // other stuff
}

class PaymentCategory {

  static hasMany = [payments: PaymentEntry]

  // other stuff  
}
```

Next, once you have a criteria instance, you need to call one of its methods, such as `list()`, to build and execute your query.

```
def c = PaymentEntry.createCriteria()

def res = c.list {
  'in'("category", categories)
}
```

A shorter version of the same thing is...

```
def res = PaymentEntry.withCriteria {
  'in'("category", categories)
}
```

Both `in()` and `inList()` are available to you, as long as you quote `in` as you did, since it's a Groovy keyword. You can read more about criteria queries [here](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-where-clause/).

Comment: But I don't want to have `payments` field in PaymentCategory. Do I really need it?